# what is the definite formula for an exponent?

Tags: computer-science, recreational-mathematics

I'm attempting to code math formulas from square 1 where i use addition to make subtraction, multiplication, division, -etc. etc. But that brung me to exponents, i felt it was simple enough, and i smacked in a repeat and a self multiplying script, and i got what i was looking for, but when i got to things like 2^0, i got 0 because variable=(2)*(2) happening 0 times = 0 and not the usual 1, then negatives started becoming an issue on the scripts complexity, while i'd like to just fix them with more scripting, i want to find the definite formula for this so as to keep things simple.

though what is this formula?

Comment: You have a bunch of answers here for ints or floats https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164964/how-are-exponents-calculated

Answer (score 0):

Just start the recursion at 0, eg :

def expo(x, y): """Computes x^y for integers x and y"""

if y==0:

```
return 1
```

elif y < 0:

"""thank you @Soham Saha for showing how to easily extend
this algorithm for possibly negative $y$"""

```
return 1/expo(x, -y)
```

else:

```
return x * expo(x, y-1)
```

Comment: Maybe add a ‘else if y<0: return 1/expo(x,-y)’ too?

Comment: this i what i was not wishing to do, while this would get me what im looking for, its relying on conditions such as "if y==0" to get values like 1 when the exponent is 0. im trying to calculate exponents without this. is there a defined equation for this that uses no if/else statements?

Comment: @JustinNeugebauer No, to my knowledge this is the *definition* of exponent for integers. There is no definite formula. While my answer was oriented toward informatics, the definition I give merely mimics the mathematical definition and write it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The only "definite" formula I can think of is the power series of x^y (the one as a function of $x$ and the other as a function of $y$).